# DOM set an images source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have a jquery and php project I am working on where users upload images to be placed in blocks. I have my uploading of images working but I am having trouble setting the img sources to the uploaded images.

```
<div class="one">
    <img id="first" src="" height="100" width="100">
</div>
```

I have have about 200 of these which I make into arrays in jquery.

```
'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']
```

Above is my url for an uploaded image in php.

I am having trouble understanding how I can set the sources in DOM as well as using DOM to clear the sources with setAttribute. If anyone can set me on the right track or give me the basic php DOM needed I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

Alright after reading a few replies I see I haven not given enough information, I need the sources to change at the server through php and a jquery change will only change the local source. Sorry for not providing enough information.

Something along the lines of:

```
 $node->setAttribute('src', "images/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] );
```

But simply put I dont really understand all the steps needed with DOM.

Comment: It would be nice to create images with src dynamically while iterating and then append to particular container. Can you show the code, where you are iterating the $_FILES['file']['name']?

Comment: I would prefer to limit the code shown, the array does not fill via iteration but rather by users clicking specific blocks to determine which block gets the image.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help you remove your src value for any images

```
function clearAllImgs()
{
    var imgs = $('.one').find('img');
    imgs.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', '')
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jquery you can set a node attribute with `$(selector).attr('name', 'newValue')`.  So for instance `$('img').attr('src', 'something')`;